# dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, powerbi

I am trying to call a Azure Machine Learning web service from Microsoft Power BI (Visualization tool) through R. The process demands input to be given as a list. So for that I am converting my input to a list in R. Below is my code.

```
dataset <- data.frame(sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM dbo.Automobile")) 
close(conn)

if(nrow(dataset)>0)
{
dataset <- dataset[,c(-1, -14)]
dataset <- na.omit(dataset)

createList <- function(dataset)
{
  temp <- apply(dataset, 1, function(x) as.vector(paste(x, sep = "")))
  colnames(temp) <- NULL
  temp <- apply(temp, 2, function(x) as.list(x))
  return(temp)
}
...
```

I am very new to R so above code is from Power BI's documentation only. But  is gives the following error :

> dim(X) must have a positive length

I tried googling this error and applied some of the workarounds like 
1. using lapply function 
2. adding `drop=F` 
but kept on returning errors.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you.

Comment: This error usually occurs when the data plugged into `apply` is not an array (e.g. it is a vector). Can you show us a small sample data set that produces the same error?

Comment: `dataset = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2)
if(nrow(dataset)>0)
{
dataset <- dataset[,c(-1, -14)]
dataset <- na.omit(dataset)

createList <- function(dataset)
{
  temp <- apply(dataset, 1, function(x) as.vector(paste(x, sep = "")))
  colnames(temp) <- NULL
  temp <- apply(temp, 2, function(x) as.list(x))
  return(temp)
}
Values = createList(dataset)
}`
I used the above code and got the same error